# Sending personalized emails with others CCed in

Tags: php, email, email-headers

I tried Googling for this, but I was unable to find anything similar. Apologies if it's already out there.

I want to send a personalized email so it will say

> Hey, [Name]

But if they Reply All, I want others to be included. Is this possible, or would the idea break the internet?

Thanks.

EDIT (Due to this apparently being poorly worded):

I need to send an email to John, and the email should be as follows

> Hey John,
>
> Just wanted to remind you about the meeting this Friday.
>
> Thanks.

Now, John should get the email, and if he does a reply all, then Amy and Sam should also be included. HOWEVER, Amy and Sam should NOT get the original email. ONLY if John does a "Reply All" should they receive an email. So essentially, the email when John gets it should say it was sent to Amy and Sam, but those should only be in the headers that the email client sees when responding, not sending.

Comment: If you are using a personalized name wouldn't you need to use a loop anyways? So you would need to send out an individual email anyways

Comment: @Chitowns24 Yes, I will need to loop. The reason I want it that way is so people can reply to everybody the email was sent to, but I don't like the "Hey everybody" greeting.

Comment: oh I see what you are saying. Well use a loop to add all the cc's in the header and then have the individual greetings $headers .= "\r\nCc:email@$domain.com";

Comment: @Chitowns24 But then, when I send it with everybody CC'd in, wouldn't they also get the email with the other person's name on it? So basically, I need them CC'd in, but never get the email, other wise if I sent it to two people, both would get two emails, one with their greeting, and one with the other persons greeting.

Comment: Oh yeah that's true, I don't think it is to be honest

Comment: `$name="Steve"; echo "Hey, $name";` or make an array.

Comment: @Chitowns24 that's what I figured. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Fred-ii- but he wants the recipient list to show up so they can all reply to eachother

Comment: Then he'll need to set an array along with a `foreach` loop. It's hard to say if he's doing this from a DB (*or wanting to use*). The question falls into both "unclear what is asking" as well as "too broad". @Chitowns24 --- Using a DB would be the easiest method.

Comment: many mailing lists work this way, the from address would be a list address, so replies go to all list member's/ mailings lists seem to falling out of vogue in favour of web forums

Comment: Yes, I'm using a database, but that's really irrelevant. I could also be using an array. Yes, mailing lists do this, but they fail in one aspect: The greeting is not personalized. Basically, I need the email to say it was sent to X people, but only 1 person actually get it.

Comment: i dont understand the edit.

Comment: Then just set a variable with the `$name` then in the loop. You would also need to create a query for the people's names from the names column. Basically the same method you would use to send everyone an email, just add the person's `row` to the query; **done deal**.

Comment: See edit. Didn't think this would be so hard to understand.

Comment: perhaps because its not possible to that as described, you can do something quite similar however with a mailing list - the reply would go to the server first that would send mail to others, not a reply all to multiple people from the clients email application

Comment: @Dagon, I know that. The question WAS if it was possible. And I quote from the original post, "Is this possible...?"

Comment: and i quote from my comment "because its not possible to that as described"

Comment: In the [`mail` docs](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), `To: ` is one of the `additional_headers` that can be set, while who to send to is one of the main parameters.  Just a guess, but if you put only one e-mail address in the `to` parameter to the function, but put all of the addresses in the `To: ` header, might it work?  I can't test.

Comment: @SuperScript can you provide a link?

Comment: no, that wont work, but feel free to test that yourself. there can be only one `to` header, so one of the two options will work not some hybrid of both

Comment: *"Essentially, I need the email to say it was sent to X people"* --- [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://php.net/mysqli_num_rows) perhaps?

Comment: I don't suppose there's a way to determine which email account the email is being viewed in? That way a custom image (that looks like text) could be used?

Comment: whats wrong with the tried and true mailing list approach, why are you trying so hard to do it another way?

Comment: @Dagon, because, one day it's to John with Amy and Phil, another it's to Amy with George and Tom, another it's to Will with Amy and John. Basically, that would require a different mailing list for each group.

Comment: i see no problem with that.

Comment: @Dagon, would you want to create an undetermined amount of mailing lists, and try to keep them straight? I think that's n!/(n-1)! possible lists, where n is an ever growing number.

Comment: table of users, table of user to mailing list, seems simple

Comment: *"I don't suppose there's a way to determine which email account the email is being viewed in? That way a custom image (that looks like text) could be used?"* --- You need to use [**sessions**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) for that.